# Difference between API 30 and API 31 Android -> App is crashing

Tags: java, android, crash

I found weird behaviour of my code which is result in crash of my app with following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong state class, expecting View State but received class com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton$SavedState instead. This usually happens when two views of different type have the same id in the same hierarchy. This view's id is id/story. Make sure other views do not use the same id.

I was looking at code, both java and xml and didn't find any duplicates even with "Find Usage" provided by Android Studio - haven't found nothing in particular.
So, I ran my app on my phone with Android 11 - it works like a charm. But it crashed in my other one phone with Android 12. Now I'm confused like "The hell is going on".
Here's my Java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener,
    NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private Button storyButton,
        specSectButton,
        webRegistryButton,
        feedBackButton,
        findUsButton,
        rssFeedReader;
private AlertDialog.Builder builder;
private AlertDialog dialog;
private Intent intent;
private ActivityMainBinding binding;
private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(view -> drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START));

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{
                        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                }, 1);

        storyButton = findViewById(R.id.story);
        storyButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        specSectButton = findViewById(R.id.sections);
        specSectButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        webRegistryButton = findViewById(R.id.eRegistry);
        webRegistryButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        feedBackButton = findViewById(R.id.feedback);
        feedBackButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        findUsButton = findViewById(R.id.find_us);
        findUsButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        rssFeedReader = findViewById(R.id.app_blog);
        rssFeedReader.setOnClickListener(this);

        drawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout;
        NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home,
                R.id.nav_our_story,
                R.id.nav_study_addresses,
                R.id.nav_e_registry_link,
                R.id.nav_feedback_to_staff,
                R.id.nav_findus,
                R.id.nav_app_blog
        ).setOpenableLayout(drawerLayout)
                .build();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    }
}

private void storyButtonClicked() {
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StoryActivity.class));
}

private void specSectButtonClicked() {
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SpecStorySectionActivity.class));
}

private void webRegistryButtonClicked() {
    intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("eu.spaggiari.classeviva");
    if (intent != null) {
        // We found the activity now start the activity
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    } else {
        // Bring user to the market or let them choose an app?
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + "eu.spaggiari.classeviva"));
    }
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void feedbackMailToButtonClicked() {
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EmailSendingActivity.class));
}

private void rssNewsButtonClicked() {
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RSSReaderActivity.class));
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
        int id = v.getId();
        if (id == R.id.story) {
            storyButtonClicked();
        } else if (id == R.id.sections) {
            specSectButtonClicked();
        } else if (id == R.id.eRegistry) {
            webRegistryButtonClicked();
        } else if (id == R.id.feedback) {
            feedbackMailToButtonClicked();
        } else if (id == R.id.app_blog) {
            rssNewsButtonClicked();
        } else if (id == R.id.find_us) {
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setTitle(R.string.created_for)
                    .setMessage(R.string.reaching_from_fornovo_FS)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, (dialog, which) -> startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            MapsLoader.class)))
                    .show().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
        DrawerCloser.closeDrawer(drawerLayout);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_our_story) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StoryActivity.class));
        DrawerCloser.closeDrawer(drawerLayout);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_study_addresses) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SpecStorySectionActivity.class));
        DrawerCloser.closeDrawer(drawerLayout);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_e_registry_link) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WebRegistryActivity.class));
        DrawerCloser.closeDrawer(drawerLayout);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_feedback_to_staff) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EmailSendingActivity.class));
        DrawerCloser.closeDrawer(drawerLayout);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_findus) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsLoader.class));
        DrawerCloser.closeDrawer(drawerLayout);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_app_blog) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RSSReaderActivity.class));
        DrawerCloser.closeDrawer(drawerLayout);
    } else if (id == R.id.dev_team) {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setIcon(R.mipmap.icon_dev_team)
                .setTitle(R.string.dev_team)
                .setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.handler_dev_team, null))
                .setPositiveButton("OK", (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss()).show().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        DrawerCloser.closeDrawer(drawerLayout);
    } else if (id == R.id.subscribe) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SendBugCrashReport.class));
        DrawerCloser.closeDrawer(drawerLayout);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setTitle(R.string.created_for)
            .setMessage(R.string.confirm_exit)
            .show().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.dismiss();
}}
```

This is XML layout file:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:forceDarkAllowed="false"
tools:context=".main.MainActivity">
<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_home"
            app:title="@string/app_name"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/black" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/app_bar_layout">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/story"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="#78ffff33"
                android:text="@string/label_our_story"
                android:textColor="#000" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sections"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/story"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="#784169e1"
                android:text="@string/specSectionButtonId"
                android:textColor="#000" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/eRegistry"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/sections"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="#78ff6347"
                android:text="@string/e_registry"
                android:textColor="#000" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/feedback"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/eRegistry"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="#78c0c0c0"
                android:text="@string/feedback"
                android:textColor="#000" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/find_us"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/feedback"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="#78ffff33"
                android:text="@string/findus"
                android:textColor="#000" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/app_blog"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/find_us"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="#784169e1"
                android:text="@string/app_blog"
                android:textColor="#000" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" /></androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? I repeat: in android 11 it works like a charm, in android 12 - it crashed with the exception mentioned in quotes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a stupid error, solved by editing themes.xml (night mode) adding .Bridge

before:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_200</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

now:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar.Bridge">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_200</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```